# NewForm not showing when adding new document to library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have recently noticed that if you add a new document in a document library in SharePoint Online without any required fields you skip the step where the form to fill out the metadata comes up.

Notice that this is not when I drag and drop a document to the library, its when i create a new document from the new button.

**Have anyone else noticed this? Is it an documented update from Microsoft and do anyone have a fix for this?**

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have any mandatory fields then that step is skipped. Ty making one of the property as mandatory and check the same scenario

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SharePoint Online 2013, In that version Microsoft introduced Drag and Drop feature for pull items into document library. While doing this action, the new form with other metadata columns are not shown. You need to go to particular item and edit the properties of the dropped item in document library.